# Show Date Before Month in Top Bar Applet

Tags: unity, indicator, time, date

I'm running 14.04 and would like to have the Time & Date applet near the far right of the upper panel show the date as *dd mmm* rather than *mmm dd*, i.e. **Fri 18 Mar 01:10** instead of the current:

[image: time & date applet]

Is there a way to accomplish this?